# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object' on GetAwaiter().GetResult()

Tags: c#, .net-core

We have used the following code to await method execution since we have sync methods that must consume async methods and this is a wrapper we have used in our project

```
public dynamic RunTask(dynamic method) {
   var result = Task.Run(async () => await method).ConfigureAwait(false);
   return result.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Seems like this line of code works fine when the method have return types ex: Task< int > but today when I have written non-return method it throws an exception when there is no return value from Task

```
   // throws exception in this case 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'
   public async Task Run(){
        await //;
   }

   // Works
   public async Task<int> Fun(){
      return await //;
   }
```

From the message, it is clearly unable to assign void to object but is there something I am missing how do I make it work void tasks. We are using .net core 3.1. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the code omitted here: `//;` - as this presumably matters. But: to be clear, `result.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is not code you should ever use. That is actively harmful. I suspect that to comment on the specific problem you're seeing, some minimal *but complete* code that shows what you're doing would be helpful. We understand that it won't compile, but we need to understand the context to usefully comment.

Comment: If the problem is just the `var result =`: note that the awaiter on a `Task` (without a `<T>`) has a `void` return type on `GetResult()`; `GetResult()` is still used to complete the loop and surface any exception, but: frankly *you shouldn't really be calling it yourself*, anyway.

Comment: @MarcGravell do we really need that code it is some await operation. its just one db call

Comment: @MarcGravell I Have updated the code and context

Comment: I repeat: that code is wrong.  You are doing "sync over async", which means you're burning a thread for no reason (and utterly defeating the point of tasks). You need to use `await` here, and change the return to be `async Task<dynamic>` instead of `dynamic`. I'm... Also very confused as to the point of trying to run something defined as `dynamic`. It seems that you're trying to do something very bizarre here, and it is really very inefficient.

Comment: @MarcGravell The library we use does not have async version but it should invoke async methods of our application and that is without blocking main thread. could you guide how to do it. If its method written by us we highly prefer async but its a method from library (where we cant do anything about it) then whats the choice you would ask to do? can u suggest some how to invoke async from sync without blocking?

Comment: but by calling `.GetResult()` **you are blocking** the main thread; that literally blocks until the work you started on the thread-pool (via `Task.Run`) completes, so you might as well have just invoked it on the main thread in the first place. If you want it to continue asynchronously: just return the `Task` itself. And there's really no benefit in using `dynamic` here; an `Action` or `Func<T>` would be more typical

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling RunTask(); with the method not returning anything? :)

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you try to return a value from a awaited method that is of type void, therefore isnt providing you with a object to return.

Comment: `public void RunTask(Func<Task> method)
{
    var result =  method().ConfigureAwait(false);
    result.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}`

Comment: that might work for awating void tasks, but bare in mind your still going to block when awaiting the task that is running on the threadpool queue when calling `Getawaiter().GetResult();` on the result of the task :)

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to block so hence added the above code from my question which is non-blocking

Comment: Well blocking was a sloppy word, maybe u prefer waiting for the task, beacuse in both yours and my case you will still be synchronously wait for the task on the threadpool to be done, wich means your still paused and waiting for the task to finish! There is no way here to not Wait :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code for your purpose, however as Marc suggested, this is not recommended practice:

```
   public dynamic RunTask(dynamic method)
    {
       if (method is Task)
        {
            method.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            var result = Task.Run(async () => await method).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return result.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of this a bad practice. The best way to async call is following await pattern. This goes something like this

```
private Task MyMethodAsync(){

}


public async void Main(){
    await MyMethodAsync();
}
```

Now it can be a bit difficult to implement await pattern if it's not already in place (as it may require await-ing all the calls in chain). What you can you do is the following:

```
MyMethodAsync().Wait()
```

This will block the calling thread and wait till the task is done. Since it's void you won't get any result and that's the main reason you are getting this exception in the first place.

Comment: I totally agree with u but it makes to change all methods to use await and the current implementation we have done do not block any thead but If we put .wait() it will block but do not want to use .wait and make blocking execution

Comment: When you do .GetAwaiter() it also blocks the thread, so there's no way around that without await